# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime' in django

Tags: python, django, datetime

I am trying to convert the date string into a specific date format but have an issue with it.

```
date = "2022-06-20T10:17:28-05:00" # getting date from DB
original_date = date.strptime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Having error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strptime'`

Comment: There's no need to use `strptime` here with ISO formats. Just use `from datetime import datetime; original_date = datetime.fromisoformat(date)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strptime` is a function of the `datetime` library and needs to be called liked this, not on the variable itself:

```py
from datetime import datetime
original_date = datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

It also looks like your format doesn't match the `strptime` format, I would suggest using the `dateutil` parser:

```py
from dateutil import parser
original_date = parser.parse(date)
```

Finally, you would be better off storing any actual date in the database with a `DateField` or `DateTimeField` rather than a string.

Comment: If I use `parse` it is giving me something like this 2022-08-08 17:01:36.686386+00:00
I want it in 'Y-m-d H:m:s' format

Comment: It gives you a `datetime` object, if you want it in a particular format then you need to use `original_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s')` note the **F** instead of a **P**